# Coloring of a normal map

Tags: graph-theory, graph-colorings

can the following proposition be proved? If so please suggest a method. Can Kempe’s Argument be used for proof ?
Proposition: A normal map has a colouring of countries by 4 colours iff the edges of the map can be properly coloured by 3 colours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a proper proof in these places:

[1) Peterson Graph by D.A. Holton & J. Sheehan](http://books.google.lk/books?id=sMSOSgbCx3kC&pg=PA72&lpg=PA72&dq=Every%20bridgeless%20cubic%20planar%20graph%20is%203-edge%20colourable.&source=bl&ots=PoYmhUn8Ad&sig=5Y3h8-JadWRagoXZdbqf_lvZTKU&hl=en&sa=X&ei=yvY0VK6fOobT7Qa5g4DwCQ&ved=0CCQQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=Every%20bridgeless%20cubic%20planar%20graph%20is%203-edge%20colourable.&f=false)

2) http://www.cs.rpi.edu/~goldberg/14-GT/18-plane.pdf

Answer (score 3):

This was proven already in the $19^{\rm th}$ century. In the following paper it is shown that the "eessentially different" $3$-colorings of the edges are in one-one correspondence with the "essentially different" $4$-colorings of the countries:

http://retro.seals.ch/digbib/view?rid=ensmat-001:1965:11::337&id=browse&id2=browse5&id3=1

Comment: Thank you! But the proof seems too complex for me. I'm a beginner in Graph theory and am incapable of understanding the proof.